# Dispatch event in SDL

Tags: c++, events, sdl

maybe I've just mised something in [docs](http://www.libsdl.org/intro.en/usingevents.html), but I can't figure out, how to dispatch an event for application from different program thread.
My pseudocode:

```
void main() {
   SDL_init();
   createThread(&secondThread);
   while(!quit) {
     /*EVENT HANDLER*/
     SDL_Event event;
     SDL_WaitEvent(&event);
     switch(event.type) {
         /*manage events*/
     }
   }
   SDL_Quit();
}
void secondThread() {
   char output[255];
   readSocket(output);  //Blocking function
   if(output=="EXIT")
      SDL_dispatchEvent(SDL_QUIT);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for [`SDL_PushEvent()`](http://wiki.libsdl.org/moin.cgi/SDL_PushEvent).

It is even documented as being thread-safe, which of course is not something one can generally assume for many libraries.

Comment: Exactly, thank you. By the way, what does thread-safe actually mean?

Comment: @TomášZato You should understand what it means for something to be thread-safe if you wrote a function called `secondThread()`

Comment: Well, I can kinda write tons of stuff without understanding it. You can either help me (you didn't) or let me google it (I did).